# How to put a checkout date and prevent the user from changing it?

Tags: html, sql

I would like to produce something similar to the checkin and checkout for a hotel reservation system. So far, I'm allowing the user to enter the booking date (which is the check in). However, I would like to implement an unedited input with the value of checkin plus number of nights.

So, after the user has selected the booking date and the number of nights, it would add them together and display the checkout date on the side (but the user can't change it). After the duration has finished, the user can book the same hotel again, without telling the user that they have already booked that hotel.

```
                <body>

                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Personal Details: </legend>
                        <label for="phone">Phone:</label><input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" required placeholder="Please enter in your phone number" pattern="[0-9]{4}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}" title="Please enter in a phone number in this format:#### ### ###">
                        <select name="country" required >
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="US">US</option>
                            <option value="UK">UK</option>
                            <option value="AUS">AUS</option>

                        </select>
                    </fieldset>
                    <br>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Booking Details: </legend>
                        <label for="date">Booking date: </label><input id="date"  type="date" name="date" min="2017-01-04">
                        <label for="numberOfRooms">Number of Rooms:</label><input id="NumberOfRooms"  type="number" name="numberOfRooms" min="1" max="4">
                        <label for="numberOfNights">Number of Nights:</label><input id="NumberOfNights"  type="number" name="numberOfNights" min="1" max="60">
                        <p>Do you require breakfast?</p>
                        <label for="yesBreakfast">Yes:</label><input id="yesBreakfast" type="radio" name="meals" value="yesBreakfast">
                        <label for="noBreakfast">No:</label><input id="noBreakfast" type="radio" name="meals" value="noBreakfast">
                        <br>
                        <!--<label for="balcony">Do you require a balcony?</label><input id="balcony" type="checkbox" name="balcony" value="yes" checked>-->
                        <br>
                        <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>

                    </fieldset>
                </form>


            </body>
            </html>
```

database tables for the book and the hotel
Book table:
id(int 11)
username(varchar 30)
hotel_id(int11)
phone(varchar 50)
date(datetime)
num_rooms(int 60)
num_nights(int 4)

Table for hotel
id(int 11)
Hotel_name(text)
Hotel_location(text)
Hotel_price(int 11)
image(varchar 500)
description(text)

Comment: Well, you've told us what you want it to do... problem is, you haven't told us what issues you are encountering.  We're not mind-readers, and we're not going to write code for you

Comment: I tried to do it  but it didn't work and then i deleted the code by mistake ...

Comment: any help?please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I suggest you use momentjs to handle date related stuff.
2. I added change event on both `date` and `NumberOfNights` to call `updateCheckout()`, in that function will handle the checkout date

hope it helps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#date, #NumberOfNights').on("change", updateCheckout);

  $('#price, #NumberOfNights, #NumberOfRooms').on("change", updateTotalPrice);

  function updateCheckout() {
    var bookingDate = $('#date').val();
    var numOfNights = $('#NumberOfNights').val();
    if (bookingDate != '' && numOfNights != '') {
      var new_date = moment(bookingDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(numOfNights, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      $('#checkout_date').text(new_date);
    } else {
      $('#checkout_date').text('N/A');
    }
  }

  function updateTotalPrice() {
    var price = $('#price').val();
    var numOfNights = $('#NumberOfNights').val();
    var NumberOfRooms = $('#NumberOfRooms').val();

    if (price != '' && numOfNights != '' && NumberOfRooms != '') {
      var total_price = +price * +numOfNights * +NumberOfRooms;
      $('#total_price').text('$' + total_price);
    } else {
      $('#total_price').text('N/A');
    }
  }

});
```

```css
#checkout_date,
#total_price {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <form action="" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Personal Details: </legend>
      <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
      <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" required placeholder="Please enter in your phone number" pattern="[0-9]{4}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}" title="Please enter in a phone number in this format:#### ### ###">
      <select name="country" required>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="US">US</option>
        <option value="UK">UK</option>
        <option value="AUS">AUS</option>

      </select>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Booking Details: </legend>
      <label for="date">Booking date: </label>
      <input id="date" type="date" name="date" min="2017-01-04">
      <label for="numberOfRooms">Number of Rooms:</label>
      <input id="NumberOfRooms" type="number" name="numberOfRooms" min="1" max="4">
      <label for="numberOfNights">Number of Nights:</label>
      <input id="NumberOfNights" type="number" name="numberOfNights" min="1" max="60">
      <label for="price">Single Room Price: </label>
      <input id="price" type="number" min="0">
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Checkout Date:</label>
      <span id="checkout_date"> N/A</span>
      <p>Do you require breakfast?</p>
      <label for="yesBreakfast">Yes:</label>
      <input id="yesBreakfast" type="radio" name="meals" value="yesBreakfast">
      <label for="noBreakfast">No:</label>
      <input id="noBreakfast" type="radio" name="meals" value="noBreakfast">
      <br>
      <!--<label for="balcony">Do you require a balcony?</label><input id="balcony" type="checkbox" name="balcony" value="yes" checked>-->
      <br>

      <label>Total Price:</label>
      <span id="total_price"> N/A</span>
      <br><br>
      <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>

    </fieldset>
  </form>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel!  How can i add the number of nights by the price of the hotel? Lets say that each night in a hotel costs £45, and a user wanted to stay for 4 nights. How would i do something like that? I will post my tables that are in the database...

Comment: @amir you mean to total price?

Comment: Yes the total price

Comment: @amir I updated the code, added a input for price, it will calculate total price using number of room x price x number of nights. an change event will triggered if you update price/number of nights/number of room, if any of those are empty, will set the total price to N/A

Comment: I have the price of each hotel, how can i extract it and use it in the code you have done? I have updated my initail  comment and added the tables that i have in php my admin?

Comment: @amir javascript are running at user's browser which is front end, if you can make ajax call to get the price and put it in the --> id="price" <-- or hide it somewhere, then you can make your calculation.

but make sure you validate at your backend(server side) before save to database

Comment: Got it. Thanks very much Daniel!! I appreciate your help a lot!! :)

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow @amir, If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as 
[Correct answe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!~~

Comment: Hi daniel, i have another problem if you dont mind helping me please? This is the problem that i'm having;  I'm trying to update my database whenever the user clicks book and the checkout date saves in the database.

Comment: @amir depend on what backend language and database you are using, you could raise a new question, make sure to be specific you can send me a link if I know how to solve it